# How to add a jar files in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp

I am very new to eclipse and i dont know how to add a jar file for database connectivity

I am using jsp and sql server 2008. Please help me out of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

1.Create a folder called lib in your project folder.

2.copy to this folder all the jar files you need.

3.Refresh your project in eclipse.

4.Select all the jar files, then right click on one of them and select Build Path -> Add to Build Path.

or

Please follow these steps in [link](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java))

Comment: @sakthi what is your problem?

Answer (score 1):

1. create a project in eclipse (file->new->DynamicWebProject).
2. Right click of the project buildpath->configurebuildpath->

(here three ways you can add jars in your project).

a. **Add Liberery** -> userlibrary ->user libraries -> new -> create the user library name (ex: dabaselibraries) -> add external jars (select your jars in your jars location of your local system)- > ok and select your newly created jars library.

b. If you have jars in same workspace in another project select **Addjars** option.

c. If  you want to add jars directly using  **Add external jars** option and select your jars in your jars location of your local system.